# jQuery maxlength attribute problem with textareas

Tags: jquery, attributes, maxlength, rel

With jQuery version 1.2.3 I'm trying to add nodes after textarea elements with attribute 'maxlength' but it doesn't work:

`$("textarea[@maxlength]").after("<b>Aint working</b>");`

This is the HTML code:

`<textarea maxlength="500">This is a test.</textarea>`
`<textarea maxlength="250">Yet another line.</textarea>`
`<textarea maxlength="125">Bar or foo, whatever.</textarea>`

The odd thing is, if I change the attribute `maxlength` with e.g. `rel` than it works just fine!

Check out this real life example:
http://www.host2000.be/_temp/jquery_tests_counter.html

PS: I'm aware of the [@attribute] notation which is no longer supported in jQuery 1.3, but this has nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your version of jQuery, it works only with a little trick. The implicit value of textarea has different values for different browsers. Firefox, for example has the implicit value of -1.

So, in order your script to work on Firefox you need to do the following:

```
$("textarea[@maxlength!=-1]").after("<b>Aint working</b>");
```

[Here](http://herr-schuessler.de/blog/selecting-input-fields-with-maxlength-via-jquery/) you can find more info about the implicit values of `maxlength` attribute.

Enjoy!

Comment: Looks like this has been fixed in jQuery 1.6, according to that article.

Answer (score 3):

Shot in the dark: it may be because maxlength is not a [valid attribute for textareas](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp).

EDIT: I've just tried your example with jQuery 1.3 and removing the @, and it worked flawlessly.

EDIT #2: Using jQuery 1.2.6 it also works without the @... Have you tried removing them?

Comment: It doesn't work without the @ in 1.2.6 but that's probably because of the reason explained below.

Comment: BTW, I tried in Opera... maybe that's the reason it worked for me :P